# Can a Syrian passport holder with an Italian visa enter Georgia (Caucasus)?

Tags: georgia-country, syrian-citizens, schengen-visas

I have a Syrian friend, who has a Syrian passport, and also a visa for Italy. He is in Jordan right now, and he wants to visit the Caucasus. Would the Italian visa let him enter Georgia also?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, he can.

The Georgian government provides a ["Do I need a visa?"](https://www.geoconsul.gov.ge/HtmlPage/Html/View?id=956&lang=Eng) wizard. It says that your friend would be able to enter on the basis of [Ordinance 256](https://matsne.gov.ge/en/document/view/2867377), which gives a list of countries "*whose visa and/or residence permit holders may enter Georgia without a visa for an appropriate period and under appropriate conditions*" "*for 90 calendar days in any 180-day period.*"

Answer (score -1):

You need to be more specific about what kind of visa does he have issued by Italy? 
Is it a long term visa or a short term visa? Or is a valid residence permit?

If it's a long term visa or residence permit - then he can enter Georgia for short stay without any problems. 
He'll have to prove that he has enough funds to support himself during his stay in Georgia.

Comment: Short-stay Schengen visas are fine too